# Enum to String Conversion

Tags: java, string, gwt, enums, type-conversion

I have a class TestCase. Inside of this I have the inner class Test. Inside the class enum OwnerType with setters and getters of the enum.

```
public static final class Test {
    public enum OwnerType {
        User("User"), Role("Role");
        private final String value;
        private OwnerType(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String toValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    private OwnerType m_ownerType;
    public OwnerType getOwnerType() {
        return m_ownerType;
    }

    public void setOwnerType(OwnerType m_ownerType) {
        this.m_ownerType = m_ownerType;
    }

    private JSONObject getJSONObject() {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put(KEY, new JSONString(m_ownerType.toString())); // Showing Error Enum to String Conversion

        return obj;
    }
}
```

`m_ownerType` is  `OwnerType Enum` so in `obj.put()` I am doing wrong related with some conversion from enum to string.

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting? Where is the variable `m_ownerType` declared?

Comment: that enum class won't compile even

Comment: Also, what errors are you getting?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran: Updated. I have a constructor for OwnerType that takes a String-typed argument.

Comment: @RohitJain : I am getting error in  obj.put(KEY, new JSONString(m_ownerType.toString())); Line. Somewhere in coverting the Enum to String.

Comment: @user3177233 I see that you're getting the error there from your comment in code, but we need the exact error message you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

java enums come with the built-in function `name()` which is the preferred way of serializing them to strings.

Comment: obj.put(KEY, new JSONString(m_ownerType.toString())); In place of this obj.put(KEY, new JSONString(m_ownerType.name())); you mean..?

Comment: @user3177233 - no, i mean put(key, m_ownerType.name());

Comment: @radai `obj` is not a `map`, it's a `JSONObject`.

Comment: @radai : Ok I tried that but It is showing that The method put(String, JSONValue) in the type JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Comment: @user3177233 So how would you resolve that error? Don't just blindly post all the issues you're facing. Try to debug the issue. Read out the error message, and think what went wrong. Of course you can't pass a `String` to a parameter type `JSONValue`. So, how would you pass a `JSONValue` as argument?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Three ways to Serialize Java Enums](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2010/01/3-ways-to-serialize-java-enums/). It depends on your use case but using the **`name()`** method looks fine in most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need in an `enum` is this:

```
public enum OwnerType {
    User,
    Role
}
```

And to get its value as String you can call `.name()` or `.toString()`:

```
OwnerType ot = OwnerType.User;
System.out.println("Owner is of type: " + ot.name());
```

That will print out *"Owner is of type: User"*. The next two will produce the same result:

```
System.out.println("Owner is of type: " + ot.toString());
System.out.println("Owner is of type: " + ot); // Implicit call to toString()
```